# „Schon“ als „ja“: Ursprung und richtige Verwendung

Tags: word-usage, etymology

In der Bedeutung des Gegenteils von *nein* ist meines Erachtens *ja* durch *schon* ersetzbar. (Die stillschweigende 0. Frage wäre, das zu bestätigen.) Das ist total nachvollziehbar, wenn man sich einen Ursprung dafür ausdenkt. Etwa folgenden:

> – Lukas, hast du deine Hausaufgaben gemacht?
>   – Schon [gemacht] (= *Kurze Form für* „Ja, ich habe die schon gemacht“.)

Die **erste Frage** ist genau zu erklären, ob dieser Ursprung richtig ist. Die zweite Frage ist vielleicht trivialer, aber nutzbarer.

Irgendwie fühle ich mich komisch, wenn ich *schon* als *ja* nutze in `Zukunft`. Denn: *Schon* bezieht sich auf eine – vielleicht implizite – Vergangenheit. Die **zweite Frage** ist, ob man *schon* als *ja* für nicht-Vergangenheit Tempora verwenden kann. Zum Beispiel:

> 1. Kommst du morgen Abend?  Hoffentlich schon, aber (…).
> 2. – Wirst du versuchen das Rauchen aufzuhören?
>      –  Schon.

Comment: Danke @Em1 für das Edit, aber im ersten Beispiel ist die Person, die die Frage stellt, diejenige die *Hoffentlich schon* sagt. Etwa wie *ich hoffe, dass du morgen kommst*.

Comment: Verstehe. Klingt aber merkwürdig so. Daher hatte ich es als Antwort interpretiert (was übrigens wiederum ein "aber" mit sich ziehen würde: Hoffentlich schon, aber ich weiß es noch nicht genau)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Wort *schon* kommt von *schön*. Als **Partikel** (und nur darum geht es im Folgenden) wird es oft als "einschränkende" Zustimmung beschrieben. Ich halte das "einschränkend" für falsch, da *schon* auch voll zustimmend verwendet werden kann

> Das schaffst du schon.

Es ist aber kein Synonym für *ja*. *Ja* ist eine Antwortpartikel, *schon* ist eher ein Adverb
*Schon* (im Sinne von *ja*) ist das Gegenteil von *nicht*. Da wo *nicht* verneint, bejaht *schon*. *Ja* ist das Gegenteil von *nein*.
Genauso wenig wie man *nein* durch *nicht* ersetzen kann, kann man *ja* durch *schon* ersetzen.

> Hast du die Hausaufgaben gemacht?
>
> Nicht/schon... funktioniert nicht.
>
> Ja/nein..... funktioniert

Wenn man hier *schon* sagt, dann ist es eine verkürzte Form eines Satzes mit *schon* als Adverb das durch *nicht* ersetzbar ist.

> Ich habe sie *schon/nicht* gemacht.

Die Tatsache, dass man ein das Positivum *schon* hinzunimmt obschon die Antwort alleine ebenfalls affirmativ ist, impliziert, dass da noch mehr ist. Das ist dann der skeptische Charakter von schon... dieses (nicht immer vohandene) Andeuten eines *abers*.

> Ja, (ich habe sie ) schon (gemacht), (aber ich bin nicht zufrieden).

Eine (deutlich) detailliertere Darstellung ist in [diesem Artikel](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/meaning-schon/) auf meinem Blog. Da sind insbesondere die Kommentare interessant.

Comment: Gut zu wissen. Ich dachte *schon* wäre die Verneigung von *noch nicht*.

Comment: Das ist dann das zeitliche "schon" (already). Darüber hab' ich hier nix gesagt.

Comment: @c.p. Im Hausaufgaben-Beispiel ist "schon" das Gegenstück zu "noch nicht" und "nicht". Verwendest du hier nur "nicht", kann das heißen, dass du sie nicht mehr machen wirst.

Comment: Gut zu wissen auch das (@ beiden).

Answer (score 5):

Schon heißt mE nicht einfach "ja". Wenn schon, dann "Ja, aber ..." (=yes, but ...) If I'd ask you a yes/no question and you replied with "schon", I'd immediately ask "aber ... ?"

"Hoffentlich schon" works as a positive reply in your example, but there are many more possibilities. It does not mean that you can simply use "schon" to mean "yes".

Comment: Sehe ich ähnlich. `Schon` kann manchmal als "zögerliches Ja" verwendet werden.

Comment: Dies lässt jedoch regionale Unterschiede außen vor. Hier (südost-bayern, d.h. bayerische und schwäbische Gegend) ist die Antwort "Schon.", ggf. auch als Ausruf "Schon!" oder bei Redseligkeit, "Ja schon!" (ohne pausierendes Komma), eine sehr sichere Antwort, also im Sinne von "Ja/Aber sicher!" -- es ist hier also nichts zögerliches vorhanden.

Comment: Um das ganze mit einem Link zu bekräftigen: ["Antwort, die Zustimmung ausdrückt, aber meist einen Einwand einleitet"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon#Antwortpartikel)

Comment: In einigen Dialekten in Österreich wird "schon?" als Ersatz für "wirklich?" bzw. "tatsächlich?" verwendet.

Comment: Thanks Ingmar, but *hoffentlich schon* is no reply (the question was edited and that was changed). Now it's ok.

Comment: @c.p. Diese Antwort gab's vor meinem Edit. Zeigt umso mehr, dass ein Muttersprachler das so nicht sagen/verstehen würde.

Answer (score 5):

Im Dialekt (ich denke da an Baden und Südbayern) wird "Schon" oder "Scho" (ähnlich wie "Freilich") im Sinne von "Aber sicher" verwendet. Das hat dann keinen zeitlichen Aspekt, wie in "Habe ich schon gemacht", sondern einen mit Nachdruck bestätigenden Anklang.

Comment: Manchmal auch verwendet als "Ja, aber was zum Teufel geht dich das an?"